# An easy question regarding Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Three schools $A, B, C$ have a total of $480$ students. Ten per cent of the students of school $A$ are going camping and the percentages for school $B$ and school $C$ are 8.5% and 15% respectively. The distances between school $A, B, C$ to the camping site are $60$ km, $40$ km and $30$ km respectively. If a student has to pay 10 cents for a kilometer, and on average, a student has to pay 400 cents, then how many students are going camping in total?

Comment: Some clarification questions: Is the 400 cents average per student just for transportation? Is that one way or round trip?

Comment: As the hold notice states, we are looking for more context to your question. If you made up a problem and you know the answer, or if you want help to solve a problem that you cannot solve yourself--that affects how we answer the question. So let us know which it is. Who am I? I am just one of the participants in this site, one who has put in enough time and effort to get the responsibility to monitor the questions, one who has at least four other such people to agree with me about your question. If you answer our questions your problem could be reopened.

Comment: @RoryDaulton So what should I do now in order to prevent my question from being blocked?

Comment: This question could be unblocked if you answer the questions in the above comments. You could prevent your future questions from being blocked if you include such information in your original questions and quickly answer clarification questions in comments to your questions. Asking good math questions is hard; expect to put some effort into your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are expected to use some form of "Guess and Check." We will not do that. Note that the average price must be for a one-way trip, since the average cost is far too low for the kids to be able to return.

We will need to assume that the numbers are *exact*, and will use some facts about divisibility.

Note that if $b$ is the number of students in school B, then $8.5\%$ of $b$ is a number divisible by $17$. Because there are only $480$ students in total, that means that the number of students going from B is $0$ (tiny school!), $17$, or $34$. That gives $0$ or $200$ or $400$ students in B, leaving $480$ or $280$ or $80$ to be distributed among schools A and C.

The students from school B pay the average of $400$ cents each. So combined, the students from A and C also pay an average of $400$ cents.

If there are $a$ students in A, and $c$ students in $C$, then they pay a total of 
$(0.1)(a)(600)+(0.15)(c)(300)$. But this is $(400)[(0.1)(a)+(0.15)(c)]$. A little algebra gives $4a=3c$. So $a=3t$ for some $t$, and $c=4t$, giving a total of $7t$.

The only one of $480$, $280$, and $80$ divisible by $7$ is $280$.

Now we know how many people are at each school, and we can answer the queston.